# Endianness when order of bits (rather than bytes) is crucial

Tags: c++, c, bit, endianness, disk

All of the questions and answers on endianness seem to centre on the order of bytes but suppose I've got a series of bits where the order of the bits is crucial. Let's say I save them to a memory stick file as an array of bytes. I may use the memory stick on a little endian machine one day and on a big endian machine the next.

Suppose the bit sequence is as follows

```
10000000 00000001
```

I'm on a little endian machine but I always save the bytes as big endian and so I reverse the bits in each byte so they're saved on the memory stick as

```
00000001 10000000.
```

Next day I read them into a uint8_t array on a totally different machine. I'm assuming (can someone confirm this) they'll end up in memory as either

```
{128,1} [little] or {1,128} [big].
```

So, if I'm on a little endian machine I should again reverse the order of bits within each byte to get back to the original bit sequence. Can anyone confirm?

I'm unsure if the machine reading the bytes (bits) assumes they're in the same endianness of the machine itself.

Comment: Statements about endianness centre on the order of bytes because typically endianness only refers to the ordering of bytes. I may be mistaken, but I don't think the order of bits in a byte changes from little to big-endian machines.

Comment: Why do you reverse the bits in the first place? Bits "just exist" within bytes, the most-significant bit remains in the same place.

Comment: Endianness only comes into play when you read and write integers which occupy more than one byte.

Comment: Bits only have endian-ness when streamed over a serial pipe, like a modem.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/byteorder

Comment: IBM mainframes numbered bits from 0 (msb) to 31 (lsb), however it's just their convention.  Transferring bytes to a mainframe did not swap the bit order, just the name of the bits changed.

Comment: The duplicate question is edited with LAST EDIT: I found this (https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6788) which says "Bit order usually follows the same endianness as the byte order for a given computer system". Does that not back up what I'm saying? I'm in the process of reading that link but it's not easy to digest. As someone commenting on the duplicate said - all of the answers are bad.

Comment: Don't swap the bit order! You will find that it Just Works. You only need to be concerned with bit order if you are dealing with low-level communication or data bus contents.

Comment: @NoComprende "all of the answers are bad." is incorrect.  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25402731/2410359) is close enough to being correct.  In your case, rather than describe code with "I always save the bytes as big endian", post the code used.  Then one can fully answer the impact of bit-endianness in your case - else this is too abstract.

Comment: https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.embedded/60464-1.php was 10 pages of the same but mostly backs up what you are all saying regarding endianness not applying to bits. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @stark Why the hide & seek event at IBM wasn't a great success: count to 100 then turn around. One second later: "100! Ready or not, here I come!" The only participants that escaped were those who quickly managed to hide inside gaps in the middle of a EBCDIC table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianess only applies to integer (and float) variables of 2 bytes or larger. It does not apply to raw data, `uint8_t` (byte) variables or arrays of `uint8_t`.

Comment: Bit endianness can show itself in bit fields member's order when overlaying with a `union`.  Typically though, bit endianness is not important in C code, but perhaps in serial communication.

Comment: @ chux - Reinstate Monica Unfortunately for me it's bit fields I'm particularly interested in. I wrote an sqlite function to pack fields into a blob using as few bits as possible. It worked a treat on my little endian laptop but I've been unable to find the info I need to make it work on a big endian machine.